# Is it possible to find out which journey builder event fired an email using ampscript

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder

What I want to do:

I want to use ampscript to find out which journey builder event fired an email so that I can make some slight tweaks to the email (with if blocks etc)

Why I want to do that:
I have a programme built in journey builder which I want to send almost exactly the same email at various points in the journey but I'd like to be able to tweak my email html slightly just to give a bit better experience.  If I can see which event fired the email then I can use if statements to make my tweaks.

Comment: There is only one Event in a Journey. Everything after that is an 'Activity'. Do you want to find out the Activity after which the email got sent?

Comment: Yes I'm interested in where in the journey the email has been triggered/sent.  There's an example journey on this page: https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/platform/digital-marketing-optimization/ - there are 2 survey thank you mails on the bottom right hand side after a decision split - how could I know (in ampscript within an email) which one of these to is being sent - in order that I can use the same email for both but with minor content changes

Comment: Decision split must be based on some contact data attribute . You can check that same condition in AMPscript in the email and make the necessary content changes. Does that help ?